# Unable to boot Win 8.1: Error bad_system_config_info

Tags: windows-8, boot, ssd, bsod

Windows 8.1, 64 bit, home-built PC, running approx 4 years.
OCZ-Vertex 256 GB drive, approx 1 year old, Drives D-H are 2 - 1 TB drives in a RAID 0 config, 8 GB RAM.

Upgraded from Win 7 to Win 8.1 approx 1 month ago.  Started getting random BSOD, most often when machine was sitting idle for a while, or overnight. Messages included CRITICAL_SERVICE_STOPPED, CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED , and a few others.  Also noticed that PC would not shutdown/reboot gracefully.  It would start to shutdown, then hang, and I would have to do 'reset button' style reboot. Updated most of the HW drivers through DriverMAX.

Came in this morning.  Unable to start due to BSOD shortly after startup with error BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO.  Rebooted, no help.  Booted from Win 8.1. disk, and tried to do a repair.  It said it found disk errors, but would not tell me which disk drive.  It rebooted automatically, but will not start.  Booted from Win8.1 DVD, ran through 'repair/reload config/save my files' option (I think it is called REFRESH).  It processed for a while, and said that "unable to refresh, no files changed'.

Booted up memtest86, ran a full pass with no errors.  Have a backup from Acronis 2014 Home version from 2 days ago.  Did a restore of drive c (MBR, partition, disk signature, etc).  Seemed to go fine.  Rebooted.  I get the windows icon for around 30 seconds, then BSOD with BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO.

My GUESS is that SSD is bad.  Is this accurate?  Could it be something else?  Is there an ISO image of a tool to test the drive?  At least read the SMART settings?  it has to be bootable, since I can't get into windows.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: First step verify your using the current firmware.  Second step using a program like BlueScreenViewer to determine what drivers are loaded when this BSOD happen.  **You will have to extract the .dmp files from the storage device in order to do this.**  I assume SafeMode doesn't work?